# First Solr Facet call on text_general pretty slow

Tags: performance, solr, facet

For a *word-frequency-in-text* query I am executing a Solr query on my index. The `facet.field` goes onto a `text_general` field using a `facet.mincount` and a `facet.limit` parameter. The query is sometimes really slow (approx. 10 seconds on my 3GB index) and sometimes executing with good speed. I think the fast queries are all because of internal Solr caching, but I don't know why sometimes the queries are so slow.

I haven't worked with [newSearcher and firstSearcher](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#newSearcher_and_firstSearcher_Event_Listeners) yet, but does it make sense to add there the common query especially for this word-frequency call?

Answer (score 1):

You should facet on non-tokenized fields.
So you can copy the field to an non-tokenized field and use that field for faceting.

Check the cache statistics for filter cache -
*Solr uses the filterCache to cache results of queries that use the fq search parameter. Subsequent queries using the same parameter setting result in cache hits and rapid returns of results.*

The queries would be cached. However, if the cache is set low, it will result into evictions and hence reduction in the performance for the same queries.

Addition, to the searches would only help in getting them cached and hence prevent the overhead for the user hitting it for the first time.

Also check the [Solr FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_speed_up_facet_counts.3F).

Comment: Thanks. But I want the word-frequency in the text. If I facet by a non-tokenized field this is not possible I think. Because then it facets by the whole text and not by the words in the text, right?

Comment: yup that would be the case then. What does your filter cache stats show ?

Comment: The filtercache e.g.

lookups : 0 
hits : 0 
hitratio : 0.00 
inserts : 0 
evictions : 0 
size : 3152 
warmupTime : 5566 
cumulative_lookups : 4540340 
cumulative_hits : 4537224 
cumulative_hitratio : 0.99 
cumulative_inserts : 3314 
cumulative_evictions : 0

Comment: And the other ones also haven 0 evictions